# My Telegram bot send a message in private but not in a supergroup

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I'm writing a telegram bot and I'm noob in PHP.
I want that the bot send a message only if a specific sticker is sent.

After the main things to do in a telegram php bot, I created this variable called sticker to memorize inside of them the file_id of the sent sticker.

```
$sticker = $update['message']['sticker']['file_id'];
```

After this, I do a check:

```
if($sticker == "CAADBAADHwADu2ztBRi6Cq8a3k66Ag")
{
    sendMessage($chatid, "Abate Bruno");
}
```

Now the problem is.. why it work in private chat but doesn't work in my supergroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a default, Bots are not listening to the messages in the groups.
Go to botfather and choose your bot, then choose "bot settings", then choose "group privacy" and then make sure that it is turned off.

Now your bot receives an update for each message sent to those groups which this bot is member of.